# Cubic zirconia additives and toxicity

Tags: toxicity

What are cubic zirconia (CZ) [gemstones](http://maxpixel.freegreatpicture.com/Colour-Gemstones-Jewel-Stone-Gem-1935724) usually colored with?

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_zirconia#Synthesis) the following dopants are being used:

- Cerium
- Chromium
- Neodymium
- Erbium
- Titanium.

Chromium is quite colorful and can be used for [green CZ](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cubic-zirconia-or-cz-608012). However I'm worried about [Cr(VI) which is carcinogenic](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/hexavalentchromium/healtheffects.html) being used, or other equally toxic substances. (manufacturing can take place in countries with less strict regulations than EU and US).

---

On the other hand, when it comes to [pottery used for cooking food](https://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodborneIllnessContaminants/Metals/ucm233281.htm) if it is properly fired practically no lead migrates to food.

So, if pottery used for boiling acidic food is safe when "properly fired", I'm assuming that the CZ (which only comes in contact with the skin) should be safe regardless of the dopants used since it can reach temperatures of 1400 °C.

### Questions:

- Is my above assumption correct?
- Is there any research on CZ toxicity or allergies.
- Could any other toxic dopants be used?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that anyone has done research on this as 1) dopants are used in very small concentrations 2) the rate of migration is likely to be so low it is unmeasurable at room temperature.